Issue while saving time without timezone in PostgreSQL
I'm encountering an issue when trying to insert a time value into a field defined as startTime in my entity in PostgreSQL. Here's the relevant code:
@Property({ type: 'time' })
startTime!: Date;

And in my service function:
await this.persistAndFlush(context, shiftType, {
  name: input.name,
  startTime: new Date('12:22:00'),
  endTime: new Date('12:22:00'),
  status: activeStatus,
});

I need to save only the time portion, but when I attempt this insertion, I get the error:
"type":"DriverException","message":"Invalid time value","stack":"DriverException: Invalid time value\n at PostgreSqlExceptionConverter.convertException

When I add the value directly through the pgAdmin, It accepts the format correctly.

How can I resolve this issue and successfully insert only the time value into the startTime field?
Thanks!

Where do you create the SQL insert? That's where you put a \n in the query, instead of a time.

This is not about the \n, its about creating Date objects from just time string, which is not possible in JS in the first place.

You can't create a Date object with just time:


console.log({ time: new Date('12:22:00') });



When you run this directly in the console or node you will get the Invalid time value as in your logs.
Mapping a time to Date object seems like a bad idea in general, especially without the timezone information. Just map it to string.

I appreciate the comment. But postgreSQL itself have an option to save time formats. I wonder how it successfully pass through the code

I dont understand what you mean, your code fails before you pass anything to the ORM, that's what I am trying to show you in my post.
